# Can I assign a variable a value within a callback function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm putting together a conversion extension for Chrome and am having trouble with pulling data from storage. Here's what I have:

```
var conversionFactor = 1;
        chrome.storage.sync.get("conversion", function(fetched) {
            var tempCon = fetched.conversion;
            if(tempCon.includes('toKG')) {
                conversionFactor = 0.45;
            } 
            else {
                conversionFactor = 2.2;
            }
        });
    alert(conversionFactor);
```

So this consistently returns 1. Shouldn't this be assigning a new value before the alert?  Failing that, what way is there to extract a value out of chrome.storage for use *outside* the callback function within the chrome.storage.sync.get statement?

Comment: it is just asynchronous...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[chrome.storage.sync.get](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) is an asynchronous operation. Move the alert into the call back function and you will see the proper value.

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("conversion", function(fetched) {
    var tempCon = fetched.conversion,
        conversionFactor;
    if(tempCon.includes('toKG')) {
        conversionFactor = 0.45;
    } 
    else {
        conversionFactor = 2.2;
    }
    console.log(conversionFactor);
});
```